# Maven dependency equivalent to MOXy

Tags: java, xml, maven, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to find the maven dependency that contains the class equivalent to

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode;
```

Here's the POM I have so far but none of the dependencies contain the XmlVariableNode class that I'm looking for. If there isn't one that contains it, does anyone know of a workaround? I'm trying to map the keys of a map to the nodes.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DropWizard</groupId>
<artifactId>DropWizard</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.easybeans.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>easybeans-modules-persistence-eclipselink-2.x</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldService</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode` is a new feature in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Repository**

```
<repository>
    <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
    <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
</repository>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlVariableNode

Comment: Blaise, may I just say that you alone have saved me so much stress, you seriously deserve like a 1000 points for how much you've helped lately lol